# Is it possible to assign a key of a keyboard to act as enter?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I many times work with CAD. With that CAD, my right hand is almost always with mouse. If I work with drawing, there will be many times I have to press the enter key to accept or to finish one command I work with. But with my right hand is handling mouse and the enter key is located on the right hand, then become not easy or not effective to do the job.

Then my question is, is any way to assign another key to be functioned as enter key (there will be 2 keys acting like enter). My favorite is Windows key as it located in the left and bottom side, located between CTRL/Fn and ALT key. Almost never I use that Windows key, so will be save enough to change the function.

Comment: Check out AutoHotKey...............https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro

Comment: Seems it will not do. What I am asking is, how to make the Windows key to act like enter key. So probably need to assign the ASCII code to be the same as enter key has. That probably 0x0D.

Comment: Autohotkey can do this for sure, it's one-liner script: `Lwin::enter` will do it. Or even better - you can buy a keyboard with extra thumb keys like X7 G800V, and use software to rebind those keys.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put this *Lwin::enter* command?

Comment: For sure, if I can find that kind of keyboard in place, I will just simply buy it.

Comment: After I tried all the HotKey, seems that it is doesn't work. Do you have another that work?